# Filter child collection with top and order by

Tags: nhibernate

I have a parent with a child collection, mapped using NHibernate. The child has a Time column. In some special cases i would like to filter the child collection, so that the collection only holds the latest X childs, based on the Time column.

Something like this: parent.Childs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Time).Take(X)

I have considered using Nhibernate filters, but it seems that they only target the where clause.

I would like to apply a filter to the child collection, so that when i retrieve a specific parent, the child collection only holds the X latest childs

How can this be done in Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

you can filter child elements in map file by add order-by="Time desc" property in collection map this property retrieve child elements in descending order by time column

Comment: You are right about the order-by part. But i still need a way to apply the TOP X clause on the query that NHibernate executes. I would like to avoid fetching the full collection from the DB.